How to download MERRA 2 data
I'm having problems to download merra 2 data, the data come as .txt and inside the file has links from the merra 2 files that i want in .nc file, how do i go from there? I mean, how can i use the nc files inside the txt.?
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.
I wish people who used merra 2 to help me
this is the file that i have 'subset_M2TMNXOCN_5.12.4_20240402_184325_.txt ' and this the files that are inside this .txt
ttps://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2_MONTHLY/M2TMNXOCN.5.12.4/doc/MERRA2.README.pdf
https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2_MONTHLY/M2TMNXOCN.5.12.4/1991/MERRA2_100.tavgM_2d_ocn_Nx.199101.nc4
https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2_MONTHLY/M2TMNXOCN.5.12.4/1991/MERRA2_100.tavgM_2d_ocn_Nx.199102.nc4
https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2_MONTHLY/M2TMNXOCN.5.12.4/1991/MERRA2_100.tavgM_2d_ocn_Nx.199103.nc4...
